# c++ qt dll not in good folder

Tags: c++, qt

I made an project in visual studio with QT, its something for in the taskbar with a tray icon.
but on other pc's i didnt saw the icon because they dont have de qicon.dll file.

the qicon.dll is in the folder: C:\Qt\4.6.3\plugins\imageformats but when i delete it there and i paste it at the exe location it dont work. how can i fix this?

so i need the dll but i want it in the same folder as the exe.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this section of the Qt documentation: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/deployment-windows.html

The relevant parts:

"Plugins work differently to normal DLLs, so we can't just copy them into the same directory as our application's executable as we did with the Qt DLLs. When looking for plugins, the application searches in a `plugins` subdirectory inside the directory of the application executable."

And:

"An alternative to putting the plugins in the plugins subdirectory is to add a custom search path when you start your application using `QApplication::addLibraryPath()` or `QApplication::setLibraryPaths()`."

I guess that answers your question.